# How can I Change user Input Text Color whenever a Button is Pressed?

Tags: text, input, colors, editor, textarea

I want to change the color of new text to be different from the color of the previous text whenever a button is pressed. For example, if the user presses the button for "red" the next text he types will be red. Then, when he presses the button for "blue" the next text he types will be blue, with the red text remaining intact...and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is any property which can be set in such a way.
But you could do it in a programmatic manner like the following pseudo-code :

1. Declare a global/common variable named **NextColor**.
2. In the **on-click event** of the respective button, you set the **NextColor** variable respectively,
   Eg :

   ```
   btnBlue_OnClick()  
   {  
       NextColor = blue;  
       //Do your work  
   }
   ```
3. Now on the **OnTextChanged** event(or a more suitable event based on your need) initialize textBox color with **NextColor**.